# ExecutorService awaitTermination method not performing as expected

Tags: java, concurrency, threadpool, executorservice

I'm trying to write a process in Java that executes a series of tasks concurrently, waits for the tasks to be done, then tags the overall process as complete. Each task has its own information, including when the individual task is complete. I'm using an ExecutorService for the process, and have boiled down the essence of the process as follows:

```
List<Foo> foos = getFoos();
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(foos.size());
for (Foo foo : foos) {
    executorService.execute(new MyRunnable(foo));
}

executorService.shutdown();

try {
    executorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // log the error.
}

completeThisProcess();
```

Each of the MyRunnable objects has a run method that makes a webservice call, then writes the results of the call to the database, including the time the call completed. The completeThisProcess method simply writes the status of the whole process as complete along with the time the process completed.

The problem I'm having is that when I look in the database after the process has completed, the completeThisProcess method has apparently been able to execute before all of the MyRunnables have completed. I'm noticing that the times that are written from the completeThisProcess method are even occasionally upwards of 20-30 seconds before the last MyRunnable task has completed.

Is there anything there that is obviously wrong with the process I've written? Perhaps I'm not understanding the ExecutorService correctly, but I thought that the awaitTermination method should be ensuring that all of the MyRunnable instances have completed their run methods (assuming they complete without exception, of course), which would result in all the sub-tasks having completion times before the overall process's completion time.

Comment: it is impossible to "write processes" in Java. You are compiling BYTECODE which is then INTERPRETED and EXECUTED by your VIRTUAL MACHINE

Comment: He doesn't mean a literal process.  Just an application that does something.

Comment: I'm not even sure how to respond to you. I'm using the term process generically. I'm writing an algorithm, is that better? Be more pedantic, please.

Comment: @jagerads more caps, anyways... My guess is that there is something wrong with your `MyRunnable` class. Your usage of the ExecutorService looks fine.

Comment: If you are sure the runnable is fine and still cannot find the problem, I would consider executing all of these sequentially outside of the ExecutorService and see if that works.

Comment: @JohnVint I suspected that as well, but I'm not sure how that could be the case. There aren't exceptions or anything. The process completes successfully, as evidenced by the data being written to the database. It's a simple Runnable class. It just seems weird that it would complete after the completeThisProcess method...

Comment: Make sure you `catch(Throwable t)` or at the very least `RuntimeException` around the entire run method.  If an exception is propagated out of the `run()` method it will never be logged.  An annoying but necessary feature of the ExecutorService is to  cache (which in your case swallows) these exceptions for the Future later

Comment: The run method has a catch for a few specific exceptions and then a catch for Exception to grab anything else. I assume that's sufficient?

Comment: Yea, that should be sufficient.  I guess my previous suggestion would be a good way to go, try running them serially without an executor service.

Comment: Does MyRunnable perhaps only trigger some action as opposed to performing it, so that this action is done by another thread after the MyRunnable finished? Anyway, show us the MyRunnable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to wait for all the threads to return is then following method can be trusted.
Make your thread class implement `Callable` interface instead of `Runnable` (In case of `Callable` `run` method will return some value. Make it return threadName.

Create a list of `Callable` Objects  and use invokeAll method which will wait for all threads to return. For the below code assume the thread class name to be MyCallable.

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(foos.size());
List<Callable> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
for (Foo foo : foos) {
  tasks.add(new MyCallable(foo));
 }
 executorService.invokeAll(tasks);
```

invokeAll returns List of future objects if you want to make use of it.

OR

you can use `CountDownLatch`.

`CountDownLatch cdl = new CountDownLatch(foo.size);`

Make it count down in run method using `cdl.countDown()` method.
Use `cdl.await` after for loop and then it will wait untill cdl become zero.

## Heading